# Connect to Mojio REST api (Python, OAuth2)

Tags: python, rest, api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect to Mojio REST api authenticated with OAuth2 with Python server code. Here's the 'manual' from Mojio: https://docs.moj.io/#/document/view/doc_oauth

I'm doing the second option there 'Authorization Code'. I don't understand what is the 'redirect_uri' parametr for. What should I pass there when I'm developing on localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" vs normal UI based oAuth workflows.  This allows you to capture the username and password in your application and authenticate with those credentials instead of a UI (which can be challenging if you are on a server).  Of course this depends on your specific requirements.

To login, via "Resource Owner" flow...

HTTP POST

Uri:

https://accounts.moj.io/oauth2/token

Body:

grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET&scope=SCOPE

Content-Type:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

This token you get back will be short lived, I would recommend getting a refresh token (longer lifetime):

To get a refresh token:

HTTP POST

Uri:

https://accounts.moj.io/oauth2/token

Body:
grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=API_TOKEN_YOU_GOT_FROM_LOGIN&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=CLIENTSECRET

Content-Type:

application/x-www-form-urlencoded